# check current route yii2

Tags: php, laravel, yii2

I just started migrating from laravel to yii2

In Laravel, I had a moment when I checked the current route, and if we are on this page, then we leave only the text, and if not, then we make this text a link

```
@if(Route::currentRouteName() === 'contact')
  <span class="contact-link active">contact</span>
@else
  <a href="{{ route('contact') }}" class="contact-link">contact</a>
@endif
```

Now I want to do exactly the same on yii2

With a regular link, everything is clear

```
<a href="<?= Url::to(['/contact']) ?>" class="contact-link">contact</a>
```

But how can you check the current page?

My controller

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('contact');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`getUniqueId()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-action#getUniqueId()-detail) on currently active action:

```php
if (Yii::$app->controller->action->getUniqueId() === 'controller/contact') {
```

or use [`$id`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-action#$id-detail) property if you want "relative" ID of current action:

```php
if (Yii::$app->controller->action->id === 'contact') {
```

Comment: I don’t know what’s wrong, but nothing helps, I threw off my controller in the post

Comment: Your action name is `index`. You should avoid naming your views differently than actions, because it is easy to confuse these two. If your controller is named `ContactController`, then you should use `Yii::$app->controller->action->getUniqueId() === 'contact/index'`

Answer (score 1):

get current `controller name:`

```
Yii::$app->controller->id;
```

current `action name:`

```
Yii::$app->controller->action->id;
```

current `route:`

```
Yii::$app->requestedRoute
```

This code can help you. Or you can modify your code based on current route.

```
<?php
if (Yii::$app->controller->id === 'mycontroller' && Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'index') {
    ?>
    <span class="contact-link active">contact</span>
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
    <a href="<?= Url::to(['/contact']) ?>" class="contact-link">contact</a>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the action in your controller is named `contact`, you could do the following:

```
{% if $this->context->action->id == "contact" %}
    <span class="contact-link active">contact</span>
{% else %}
    <a href="<?= Url::to(['/contact']) ?>" class="contact-link">contact</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I don’t know what’s wrong, but nothing helps, I threw off my controller in the post

Comment: @Hector Your action is named `index` not `contact`. As I said in my answer, it was assumed your action was `actionContact`. Replace `contact` with `index` in the `if` conditional and try again.

Comment: but my index is used on all pages

Comment: @Hector I've no idea what you mean or how it is relevant?